# Efficient way of inserting elements in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am unsuccessful in turning this function into a vectorised one:

```
a=np.asarray([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
inds=np.asarray([0,2])
vals=np.asarray([10,12])
def new_insert(arr,inds,vals):
    ret=np.zeros((arr.shape[0],arr.shape[1]+1))
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        ret[i]=np.insert(arr[i],inds[i],vals[i])
    return ret
print new_insert(a,inds,vals)
```

With output:

```
[[ 10.   1.   2.   3.]
 [  3.   4.  12.   5.]]
```

Any helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to a 1d view of your array `a`:

```
shape = a.shape
a.shape = np.multiply(*shape)
```

recalculate indexes for 1-d array:

```
ind1d = [i+e*shape[0] for i, e in enumerate(ind)]
```

insert in 1d array

```
b = np.insert(a, ind1d, vals)
```

and reshape result back to 2d

```
b.shape = (shape[0], shape[1]+1)
```

So, finally, we get

```
>>> b
array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 3,  4, 12,  5]])
```

An onliner, proposed by @askewchan in comments, using `np.ravel_multi_index` helper function to flatten index:

```
>>> np.insert(a.flat, np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(ind.size), ind), 
...               a.shape), vals).reshape(a.shape[0], -1)
array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 3,  4, 12,  5]])
```

Comment: In one line, `b = np.insert(a.flat, np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(ind.size), ind), a.shape), vals).reshape(a.shape[0], -1)`

Comment: I just started using this and figured out that it doesnt work when you want to insert to the rightmost position of the array because `insert` does not cover that case. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Figured I'd post my comment to @alko's answer as an answer, since it looks a bit confusing as one line:

```
b = np.insert(a.flat, np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(ind.size), ind), a.shape), vals).reshape(a.shape[0], -1)
```

This is basically the same as @alko's but it has a few advantages:

- It does *not* modify `a` itself, by using the `a.flat` iterator instead of actually changing the shape of `a`.
- Avoids potential bugs by using the `np.ravel_multi_index` to create the `ind1d` array instead of doing it manually.
- It is a tiny bit (10%) faster.

In steps similar to alko's, this is what it does:

```
ind1d = np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(ind.size), ind), a.shape)
```

where `ind` refers to column index, so use `np.arange` to refer to row index.  Then, insert into the `a.flat` iterator instead of the reshaped `a`:

```
b = np.insert(a.flat, ind1d, vals)
```

Finally, reshape:

```
b = b.reshape(a.shape[0], -1) # the -1 allows any shape at the end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments and explaining as well.

Comment: Hey this method doesn't cover the case where the index points to the last element, i.e. when we have to insert to the rightmost of the array. Do you have any idea what I can do?